# Having trouble navigating Magento documentation

Tags: magento, phpdoc

I am brand new to Magento and the documentation, primarily the phpDocs, are difficult to navigate. For example,

```
$attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($id);
```

In the php doc for [Class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Set](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Eav/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Set.html)  there is no mention of the method getAttributeSetName() either in inherited methods or otherwise and yet this works.

```
$attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($id);
echo $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName();
```

So I suppose I have several questions.

1. Can someone explain to me why the documentation is this way?
2. Where I can find the mysterious getAttributeSetName() method in the phpDocs?

My theory is that there is some inheritance or a design pattern implementation going on that I'm not understanding, maybe someone can shed some light on this for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to fry your brain, take a look at the source code for `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Set` and follow the inheritance chain all the way back.  You won't find a `getAttributeSetName` method defined anywhere.

All Magento objects that inherit from `Varien_Object` can have arbitrary data members set on them.  Try this.

```
$attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($id);
$attributeSet->setFooBazBar('Value');
var_dump($attributeSet->getFooBazBar());
var_dump($attributeSet->getData('foo_baz_bar'));
var_dump($attributeSet->setData('foo_baz_bar','New Value'));
var_dump($attributeSet->getFooBazBar());
```

You can also get all the data members by using

```
var_dump($attributeSet->getData());
```

but be careful dumping these, because if there's a data object that has a circular reference and you're not using something like xDebug, then PHP will have a fit trying to display the object.

Magento stores data properties in a special `_data` array property.  You can get/set values in this array with `getData` and `setData`.  Magento also has implemented magic getting and setter methods, so when you say something like

```
$object->getFooBazBar();
```

The method `getFooBazBar` is transformed into the data property `foo_baz_bar`. and then `getData` is called using this property.  It's a little tricky to get your head around, but once you get it you'll start to see how much time you can save using this pattern.

One side effect of this is, of course, it's impossible to infer what data properties any object might have by looking at it's class file, so there's no phpDocs for these methods.

Comment: I'm going to start trying to learn a subject with more hard and fast answers - theology. Thats it, my copy of your book has sat unread on my hard drive long enough...time to cowboy up. Maybe I'll have an epiphany.

Comment: Where might one find a list of all of these data properties for each one of the more common magento objects (products, catalog, ect.)? The wiki, while full of useful information is still lacking. Would I be able to find these values in the database?

Comment: Nowhere.  Some models will have this information in the database.  EAV models will depend on how they're configured, hybrid models may have data from anywhere, and even plain old models that inherit from Mage_Core_Model_Abstract with a 1to1 property/column relationship may have data set by means other than the initial population.

Comment: The "property" and "method" tags in the class-level docblock are designed specifically for such magic stuff.  If those tags were added, I wonder if this kind of confusion might be mitigated.

Comment: @ashnazg How do you use the property tags on an EAV model, when you don't know what attributes a end-client-user has created for it?

Comment: I was presuming that at some point in the chain of inheritance, whether it be a Magento parent class or something farther down in client code, tags to highlight magic items in play could be written in a class docblock.  If a child is the one _introducing_ the magic items, it should be responsible for documenting them, IMO.

Comment: @ashnazg The problem is the magic method in play change depending on how the system is configured.  `$product->getShirtSize()` is a valid method in some systems for some products, but not in other systems for other products. (also, FWIW, the talk is Magento 2 will remove the magic methods, in favor of `getData` and `setData`.